# Does the verb 'to tank' meaning to lose deliberately, or fail to finish, only apply to lawn tennis?

Tags: meaning, colloquialisms, sports

The Australian tennis star, Nick Kyrgios, is proposed in [the Australian press](http://www.smh.com.au/sport) to have *tanked* in his second set at Wimbledon, yesterday.

According to the OED sense 6 of *tank* when used as a verb appears to apply exclusively to Lawn Tennis. Do contributors agree with this? And what is the origin of *tank* when used in this way?

> 6. intr. In Lawn Tennis, to lose or fail to finish a match deliberately; to default. slang.
>
> 1976   Times 30 Sept. 11/5   Too many..singles players do not enter
>   for the doubles. Either that, or they scratch or ‘tank’ (in boxing
>   parlance, ‘take a dive’).
>
> 1979   Guardian 13 Jan. 11   But it is ironic that Connors, a player
>   generally considered too honest to ‘tank’ to anyone, should be the one
>   to suffer.

Comment: The slang _to tank_ can be used in the meaning "to fail" at anything. _fail completely, especially at great financial cost.
"the previous movie had tanked at the box office"_

Comment: Yes, tank is used to mean failure in many contexts. I often hear it in reference to the stock market, for example.

Comment: @mplungjan That seems to me to be a different sense - meaning simply *to fail*. In this case the player is accused of having deliberately failed. And it is that sense which is recognised by the OED, but as only applicable to tennis.

Comment: I note that someone has voted to close the question on the basis that it is not about the English language???

Comment: I've heard it used in chess tournaments. Probably elsewhere if I think a while.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood the question as posed. My apologies.

Comment: @WS2: Interesting question. +1. I think you should format the post to highlight the losing **deliberately** part. Otherwise it could be taken to mean failure in general.

Comment: For the sense of "tank" that you seem to be looking for, "tanking" can mean either not trying too hard to win, or trying to lose on purpose. It's been used in that way in tennis (er, on all surfaces), and also in other sports. It's used in those sports where a player can try to be gaming the system to give themselves an advantage in the long run. E.g. Bill knows he doesn't have a chance against the #1 player in a singles match, so tanks his match to save his energy for doubles. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) E.g. Sue shows up for her doubles, but because she surprisingly made it to the singles final, she chooses to tank her doubles match which isn't anywhere as important as the singles final. E.g. After losing the 1st set, Tom tanks his semi-finals match in a warm up tournament so as to not aggravate an injury before the US Open in two weeks. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In that article, the player actually didn't tank the match, imo--rather, he pouted for some number of games within one set--for he later actually won a set. Professional tennis players will often "give up" a set if they get behind by a break or two, because they want to save their energy for the next set. That's what that player sorta did, he gave up a set (he was a break down, I think) in the middle of the match due to, er, pouting reasons--but he had no intention of giving up the match (i.e. "tanking"), which you can tell by the match score.

Comment: @F.E. The game is known as 'lawn tennis' even when played on a hard surface - as opposed to [real tennis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_tennis)

Comment: @F.E. Your earlier remarks are valid, but trying to understand what is going on in the mind of Nick Kyrgios may be a step too far.

Comment: Certainly well-known in the US, meaning "failed miserably".

Comment: @HotLicks But with the added implication of failed deliberately?

Comment: @WS2 - No.  The term is often used to describe a computer system crashing, eg.

Comment: @HotLicks yes. That has been my understanding. But todays *Sydney Morning Herald* posed the question *Did Kyrgios tank?* - meaning 'did he lose a game deliberately?'. And that usage is confirmed by an entry in the OED - specifically relating it to tennis. So does it have a different meaning in tennis to elsewhere?

Comment: @WS2 - Well, I don't follow tennis nor do I follow most other sports, especially those outside the US.  My experience with the term has been mainly in non-sports contexts.  (But "Sydney Morning Herald" implies Australia, and those Aussies have lots of jargon different from the rest of the world.)

Comment: @HotLicks This is not something Australian - like a *didgeridoo*. It is confirmed in the OED, and they have not marked it as Australian either.

Answer (score 4):

Its etymology shows that its meaning related to sports is quite recent as well as its other usages meaning to fall, sink:

[to tank](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=tank&searchmode=none):

> - 1900, "to put into a tank," from tank (n.). ***Meaning "to lose or fail" attested from 1976, originally in tennis jargon, specifically in an interview with Billie Jean King in "Life" magazine, Sept. 22, 1967:***
>     "When our men don't feel like trying," she says, "They 'tank' [give up]. I never tanked a match in my life and I never saw a girl do it. The men do it all the time in minor tournaments when they don't feel like hustling. You have to be horribly competitive to win in big-time tennis."
> - Sometimes said to be from boxing, in some sense, perhaps from the notion of "taking a dive," but evidence for this is wanting.

(Etynomline)

According to OLD and other dictionaries, the *transitive usage of tank* appears to be common only referring to sport matches, while its *intransitive use* is quite popular in Wall Street for instance. I feel 'to tank' is also used transitively outside sport contexts on a colloquial basis.

[To tank](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tank_2):

> - ***[intransitive]*** (North American English) (of a company or a product) to fail completely
>     The company's shares tanked on Wall Street.
> - ***[transitive, intransitive]*** tank (something) (North American English, sport) to lose a game, especially deliberately
>     *She was accused of tanking the match.*

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20market%20tanked%2Cthe%20stock%20tanked&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20market%20tanked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20stock%20tanked%3B%2Cc0): *the market tanked, the stock tanked.*

[Tank](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tank):

> - To place, store, or process in a tank.
>     v.intr.
> - (Informal) To suffer a sudden decline or failure: *The stock market tanked yesterday.*

(AHD)

Comment: The OLD definition seems more akin to how I perceive the expression, too. I don't know whether perhaps Australians use it only for tennis, but I would certainly have no qualms about using it for just about any type of match.

Answer (score 2):

***'Tank' as a slang verb***

An Elephind search finds several instances of *tanked* in the sense of "gave up" or "stopped trying to win" or "never tried to win" in the context of tennis—but the earliest match for the term that I could find is from wrestling. From "[Wrestlers Top Race: Lambros' Men Topple Dexter in Big Match](https://digmichnews.cmich.edu/cgi-bin/michigan?a=d&d=WashtenawSREP19720120.1.1&txq=%22tanked%22)," in the *Saline [Michigan] Reporter* (January 20, 1972):

> Dancing, cheering, tears of joy, congratulations and just an overall atmosphere of frenzy folloed Saline's thrilling upset wrestling victory over league rival Dexter last Thursday. In a tremendous 12-man effort, the Hornet matmen stunned the defending champions 2920 and have now got a firm headlock on first place.
>
> Coach Tino Lambros said following the match, "It was a great overall effort by the entire team. No one **tanked out** on us. It has to be the best overall team performance this season. Really, it’s just beautiful. These guys worked hard and went out there and did the job. They really deserved to win."

This is five years after the instance cited in user66974's answer from tennis player Billie Jean King, quoted in Life magazine of September 22, 1967. Elephind doesn't link to that magazine article, but it does find a tennis-related instance from Jane Gross, "[Borg Simply Wants to Be the Best Ever](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19790828.1.35&txq=%2522tanked%2522)," in the *San Bernardino [California] Sun* [August 28, 1979):

> Borg's attitude in difficult competitive situations still lagged behind his physical skills, and occasionally he seemed to give up in the middle of the match. "I thought he was a bore," said Ted Tinling, a former British player who is now a world-renowned designer of tennis clothes. "He was solemn, detached beyond his years. He often sulked and he sometimes **tanked**."

But the verb also appears in the context of boxing in Paul Oberjuerge, "[What Is Duran Trying to Feed Us?](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19801127.1.81&txq=%2522tanked%2522)," in the *San Bernardino [California] Sun* (November 27, 1980), discussing the welterweight rematch between Roberto Duran and Sugar Ray Leonard:

> As the day wore on, this was the consensus of informed opinion:
>
> Duran quit. The awe-inspiring, all conquering hero of Panama, winner of 72 fights (55 by knockout) *manos de piedra*, simply **tanked** it.
>
> "I don't know why no one wants to accept that," said a veteran boxing man who was at ringside. "He just quit. He was getting killed. He would have been knocked out if the fight continued. There's absolutely no doubt in my mind about that."

A much more recent instance where *tanking* appears in a nonsports setting in the sense of giving up or throwing in the towel appears in "[Nonprofit to Help Educate Young Women](https://newspapers.bc.edu/cgi-bin/bostonsh?a=d&d=bcheights20070924.2.47&txq=%22tanking+the%22)," in the *Boston [Massachusetts] Heights* (September 24, 2007):

> Limaj agreed with Cahill that it was her personal connection to all of this that was the ultimate driving force behind starting the program. "But," she said, "there was a point about two-thirds of the way in when the program had been developed and the legal documentation completed, but we weren't even coming close to raising the kind of money we'd need. At that point, I seriously considered **tanking** the whole thing and giving back everyone's money." She admitted that she didn't share these concerns with Cahill or Bolster because she did not want to disappoint them.

---

**The prehistory of 'tanked': 'tank job' and 'went into the tank'**

"Tank job" in the sense of "dive" or "intentional loss" also aopears in "[Galento Matched With Abe Feldman](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SCEN19390222.1.8&txq=%2522tank+job%2522)," in *Santa Cruz [California] Evening News* (February 22, 1939):

> MIAMI (U.P.) — Tony Galento, whose Falstaffian feats threaten to overshadow his punching prowess, hopes to regain some of his waning prestige tonight with a quick knockout over Abe Feldman, a veteran who never has been involved in a **tank job**.
>
> Alarmed at the sharp decrease in demands for a Joe Louis-Galento heavyweight title fight following the malodorous ending of Tony's recent bouts, his manager Joe )Barnum) Jacobs, figured the most effective restorative for lost lustre would be an impressive victory over a man of unquestioned honesty.

From Harry Ferguson, "[Social Crisis Occurs in Cauliflower Row](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth282405/m1/5/zoom/?q=%22tank%20job%22&resolution=2&lat=5130.665663979109&lon=1162.0545522490713)," in the *Sweetwater [Texas] Reporter* (October 15, 1941):

> The boxing commissioners, like the late Marshal Foch, cling to the theory that an offense is the best defense. When in doubt, they say, charge. They claim Nova gave a dismal performance while trying to elude Louis, wear him down and then come on to win. There is no suggestion that Nova did what is known in Cauliflower Canyon as a "**tank job**"; the commissioners merely take exception to his strategy.

From Whitney Martin, "[Sports Writers Know How Pollsters Feel...](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SCS19481107.1.8&txq=%2522tank+job%2522)" in the *Santa Cruz [California] Sentinel* (November 7, 1948):

> "Lookit," they [sports writers] will say. "They [pollsters predicting a Thomas Dewey win in the 1948 presidential election] didn't have to worry about the possibility of a **tank job**, or a phoney close one to set things up for a rematch, or a bad decision. They knew both men would be in there pitching, that everything was on the up and up.

And from "[Fans Boo As Win Is Called 'Fake' In Matthews Bout](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=MT19520429.2.69&txq=%2522tank+job%2522)," in the *Madera [California] Tribune* (April 29, 1952):

> No ringsiders could be found who saw the blow [a left hook] connect with Kaplan. A San Francisco sorts writer estimated the hook "appeared to miss the top of his head by at least six inches."
>
> Fans booed lustily as Kaplan was helped to his corner and dosed with spirits of ammonia.
>
> There were cries of "dive," and "**tank job**" from galleryites. Kaplan failed to land a single solid punch against his lighter opponent. The New York fighter weighed in at 194 pounds for Matthews' 182.

And from "[Chavez, Wills Reveal Scandals In Boxing Probe](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=DIL19560329.2.79&txq=%22went+into+the+tank%22)," in the *[Urbana-Champaign, Illinois] Daily Illini* (March 29, 1959):

> LOS ANGELES (AP)—Former heavyweight Harry Wills and veteran lightweight Carlos Chavez supplied the fireworks Wednesday as the special governor's committee continued to unearth alleged scandals in its exhaustive probe of the fight game.
>
> Chavez, wilting under forceful examination by investigator T. E. Billings, admitted he "**went into the tank**" in the first round of a rematch with Art Aragon at the Olympic Auditorium here in November 1950. He claimed he was too "sick" to fight.
>
> Wills, 31, volunteered testimony that he "double-crossed" the handlers of Freddie Beshore in a fight in Baltimore, Nov. 20, 1950, by outpointing the then title-hoping Beshore in 10 rounds.
>
> But, the now retired Wills said he "**went into the water**" in a match with Jimmy Bivins in Baltimore Jan. 22 , 1951, losing by a knockout and losing a decision to Harry (Kid) Matthews in Spokane, Wash., Nov. 8, 1952.
>
> ...
>
> Wills, testifying later, charged Ginsberg wanted the rematch on the condition that Wills would agree to a **tank job**. Wills said Ginsberg then backed out because he was afraid "I'd cross them up again."

---

**An early colloquial usage of 'went into the tank'**

An interesting instance of "went into the tank" in a different colloquial sense appears in "[Herd Badly Diseased](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045366/1903-09-01/ed-1/seq-6/#words=%22went+into+the+tank%22)," in the *Minneapolis [Minnesota] Journal* (September 1, 1903):

> After they [the cows] were killed, however, it was found that sixteen of the eighteen were so badly diseased that they could not be used for meat, and they "**went into the tank**," where none but the poorest and most worthless of cattle go.

It's unclear what "the tank" here refers to but it may mean some type of rendering vat. The same term appears in "[The Live Stock Situation](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=WAF19151015.2.59&txq=%22went+into+the+tank%22)," in the *[Chicago, Illinois] Wallace's Farmer* (October 15, 1915):

> In 1907, when the new federal meat inspection law went into effect, there were 708 packing plants where federal inspection was maintained, and in those plants there were condemned in that year 28,497 whole cattle carcasses, while parts of 93,174 carcasses were likewise cut down. In 1914, a total of 893 establishments in which federal inspection was had, there were 51,417 whole cattle carcasses condemned, and parts of 183,085 carcasses **went into the tank**.

The earliest instance of "went into the tank" in the sense of "didn't try to win" in a sporting context draws a direct connection to the slaughterhouse sense of the term. From "[Bill Corum Says...](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19390202.1.17&txq=%2522went+into+the+tank%2522)" a New York City–datelined column published in the *San Bernardino [California] Sun* (February 2, 1939):

> "Do you think that a clever boxer like John Henry Lewis would let a gifted sap like Joe Louis lead with a right? What I mean is, the fight was fixed. John Henry **went into the tank**. What do you think?"
>
> I think, Wally, that if John Henry **went into the tank**, so does a steer in the slaughter house. And so does a criminal in Germany when the gent in the full dress suit drops that meatchopper on his throat.

---

***Conclusions***

The OED's association of early slang use of the verb *tank* in the sense of "give up" or "deliberately lose" with tennis receives important support from [Etymology Online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tank), which cites the 1967 Billie Jean King interview in *Life* magazine. But OED's implicit claim that *tank* as a verb is used in this sense only in the context of tennis is clearly incorrect.

Indeed, the earliest Elephind match for *tank* (or rather "tank out") in the sense of "quit" appears in a 1972 article on a wrestling match. *Tank* also arises in the context of a commentary on the the famous "*¡No màs!*" boxing match in 1980 between Roberto Duran and Sugar Ray Leonard. So although the link to tennis is strong, it is not unique. And subsequently people have sometimes used *tank* in the relevant sense in contexts that have nothing to do with sports.

At least as significant is the long historical connection between *tank* as a noun and as an adjective in specifically boxing-related usage. Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang*, first edition (1960) offers these relevant entries:

> **tank** ... *v.i.* To fail. *Not common.* *adj.* Fixed. *Said of a prize fight.* See **tank fight**. ...
>
> **tank, go in the** To allow oneself to lose a prize fight; to throw a fight. *Suggested by "take a dive."* Cf. **tank fight**.
>
> **tank act** = **tank fight**.
>
> ...
>
> **tank fight** A prize fight in which one fighter is paid or bribed to lose, as by his opponent or gamblers; a fixed prize fight; one in which a fighter takes a dive. Cf. **go in the tank**.
>
> **tank job** = **tank fight**.

As of 1960—seven years before the seminal Billie Jean King interview—there were numerous established slang expressions related to *tank* in boxing lingo that had to do with losing on purpose. Meanwhile, Wentworth & Flexner doesn't mention tennis at all.

Wentworth & Flexner's only mention of *tank* as a verb is in the related (but not identical) sense of "fail"—so it may very well be that tennis is the venue where *tank* in the sense of "quit" or "not try to win" or "try to lose" originated. But even if that's the case, I consider it likely that tennis drew on the older boxing lingo of "tank job" and "going into the tank" as the source of its notion of *tanking*.

Comment: @WS2: I think that Wentworth & Flexner's view that "go in the tank" was suggested by "take a dive" is probably correct. In boxing you can end up sprawled out on the canvas after being leveled by a punch—or you can fall down after pretending to have been struck by a knockdown or knockout punch. Just as we might use "diving down" to describe soldiers hurling themselves to the ground as an incoming mortar or rocket descends nearby, we might call voluntarily falling to the canvas "diving." And diving of course, suggests diving into water—or more specifically into a tank (pond or pool) of water.

Answer (score 0):

In gentlemanly Edwardian English one might claim a contingency of the petrol tank as the reason one failed to complete the course. Perhaps the engine was too ravenous or the tank became pierced. This would be largely less embarrassing than admitting one's vehicle was in poor repair or one's skills weren't as they should be. The vehicle simply ceased to function. In modern American parlance one would claim "I ran out of gas." One of questionable character might claim this dishonestly, hence the second, scornful sense of "copped out" or "bailed out" (c/c "blame the chalk"). One can exercise interchangeability of synonym with sentences like "The economy (ran out of gas / tanked)" and "You can hear Paul McCartney (bail / tank) on his second high-note 'vain' and laugh about it." EG: "Why did you bail out?" "The engine tanked!"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).